# Accessing related models in many to many relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relational-database

I have three tables `users`, `profiles` and `roles`. The `users` and `profiles` tables has one to one relationships and the `users` and `roles` has many to many relationships using a pivto table `role_user`. In the `Role` model, I retrieve related users:
**Role model**

```
public function users() 
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

My problem is that the above method only retrieves the users and not their profiles. In fact, I want to get users as well as their profiles using a role model and then paginate them.

```
public function getUsers($role)
{
   return $role->users()->paginate(50);
}
```

**So, how can I retrieve users and their profiles using a Role model?**

Answer (score 0):

In your User model you define your Profile relationship:

```
public function profile() 
{
   return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
}
```

and then when you call the getUsers() method you can eagerload the users and their profile:

```
$role = Role::with('users.profile')->find($id);
$result = getUsers($role);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to retrieve users and their profiles. With your codes I can only get users. There is a one to one relationship between users and profiles.

Comment: @max256, got you now! Edited my answer to work with user profile instead of roles